# NHibernate save children element FK going NULL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, null, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

So, I have a list of children on my parent object, and I want to persist them on my SQL Server. When I run the application for the first time, all the children get their FK correctly, but when I run it again and no new parent is added, the new child(of an existing parent) doesn't get it's parent FK, just NULL. How can I map the parent FK on my child mapping for those situations?

I've tried the `Inverse()` method, but as I need the parent key to be generated all children gets null anyway. I need something like, if the parent is new, then the parent will update it's children FK, but when only the child is new I would need it to do the `Inverse()` method, is it possible?

Some more info:
Every time I call the ParentPersist method, and it cascades as needed. I've added the `AddChild()` method to set the *ParentId* when a new child is added to the list, it's working as I debugged it, so the child is setting it's ParentId correctly.

The objects are like the following:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual IList<Child> Children{ get; set; } 


 public virtual void AddChild(Child ch)
    {
        ch.IdParent = this.Id;
        Children.Add(ch);
    }
 }

 public class Child
 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual int IdParent {get;set;} 
 }
```

And my mapping:

```
public class ParentMapping : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMapping ()
    {
        Id(cso => cso.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        ...
        HasMany(cso => cso.Children).KeyColumn("IdParent").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class ChildMapping : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMapping ()
    {
        Id(cso => cso.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic (e.g. `Add()` method in Parent, `Inverse()` mapping) was OK. You were almost there. There is only one BUT...
In general, the proper *(if not only correct)* solution is to use **objects to express realtion** and ***not*** just the ***ValueType/int values***. That's why we call it [ORM - Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Object in C# should look like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    ...
    // correct mapping of the children
    public virtual IList<Child> Children{ get; set; } 

    // this method uses the below updated Child version
    public virtual void AddChild(Child ch)
    {
        // this is replaced
        // ch.IdParent = this.Id;
        // with this essential assignment
        ch.Parent = this;
        Children.Add(ch);
    }
 }

public class Child
{
    ...
    // instead of this        
    // public virtual int IdParent {get;set;} 
    // we need the reference expressed as object
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; } 
}
```

So, now, once we have objects in place, we can adjust the mapping like this:

```
// parent
public ParentMapping ()
{
    ...
    HasMany(cso => cso.Children)
       .KeyColumn("IdParent")
       .Inverse() // this is essential for optimized SQL Statements
       .Cascade.SaveUpdate() // All delete orphan would be better
       .Not.LazyLoad();
}
...
// Child
public ChildMapping ()
{
    ...
    References(x => x.Parent, "IdParent"); // it is a to use Inverse() 
}
```

With this Business Domain Model and the mapping *(`Inverse()`, assigning bothe relation ends in `Add()` method...)*, NHibernat will have enough information to always (insert, update) issue proper SQL statements

*NOTE: One could ask why to map `Parent Parent { get; set; }` and not just the `int IdParent { get; set; }`... In fact, if we would have existing Parent (with NOT transient ID, i.e. `> 0`) - there won't be any difference. The trick/problems would appear on a `new Parent` insertion. Almost always, assignement of the children comes before the Parent is persiseted (flushed), and its ID is recieved from DB (sql server identity). And that could/would cause the `child.IdParent == 0` ...

We should remember, that in general - ORM is about objects, i.e. relation is represented by Reference types.*

Comment: Great to see that, Enjoy amazing NHibernate ;)